# Using all data available to the modeller or use subset?

Tags: r, machine-learning, prediction

I am developing a predictive model using Accident and Emergency Data. I am aiming to predict which patients will go home or stay in hospital. I have available over 10 years of data that can be used to build a model. Well over a million observations. However in that 10 years there have been many changes in A&E procedures as well as a couple abnormal natural disasters that will have affected the target variable.

For example 10 years ago some patients with borderline conditions could be sent home but recently changes in protocol now mean that those patients will (usually) always be admitted to hospital. Also initiatives in the department have seen improvements in Data Quality providing richer higher quality data in more recent years.

My question is are there guidelines or general practices for selecting data for modelling? Is it good/bad to use all available data for model development? If there has been a significant change in process that will be captured in the data will this adversely affect my models? Or use data relevant to the problem at hand? My concern is that using all available data a model ends up using data that no longer reflects current practice in the business.

I am not talking about the practice of creating training and test sets. This is about how to select data prior to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the last year as your test data and try to include all years and only the most resent years and compare the results. Another solution which are commonly used is to weight resent observations higher. So use a weight function with decaying rate and use last year as test data. E.g $w_{year-2} = 1$,$w_{year-3} = \alpha$ ,$w_{year-4} = \alpha^2$ ...

So in short try it out for your dataset and threat it as a hyperparameter